# Flutter Routing

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a home/main screen on my app that is displayed once a user has been authenticated, I did not include this screen on the routes parameter on the MaterialApp class because it got initialized before it was called and caused many errors:

```
        home: WelcomeScreen(),
        initialRoute: "/splash",
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          "/welcome": (_) => WelcomeScreen(),
          "/splash": (_) => SplashScreen(),
          //"/main":(_)=>Main(),
        });
```

So this is how I open the main screen:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context)=>Main()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Now I have a screen where I need to pop the stack until the home screen when a process has been completed but since the main screen was not added to the `routes` I cannot navigate to it using

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("home screen here"));
```

Is the a way to add the home screen to the routes only when it's time for it to be initialized?

**Update**:
I tried calling the main screen like this

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context)=>Main(),settings: RouteSettings(name: "/home")), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

But I get a `Could not find a generator for route` exception when using this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/home", ModalRoute.withName("/home"));
```

Comment: try to just push new material route, without removing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on here.

Adding `"/main"` to the list of named routes should not cause any problems because `routes` is just contains `WidgetBuilder`s, that means `Main` constructor is not called until you push `"/main"` and there should be no initialization issues. Not sure what causes your issue, an error message would help.

---

It might be a good idea to remove the slashes from your named routes, because a slash implies that there is a route named `"/"` that is the parent of `"welcome"`, `"splash"` and `"main"`. I think what you actually want are three top-level routes:

```
<String, WidgetBuilder>{
  "welcome": (_) => WelcomeScreen(),
  "splash": (_) => SplashScreen(),
  "main":(_) => Main(),
}
```

---

Another issue I spotted is that you are adding `/main` to the named routes list, but in the end you are pushing `/home`. Maybe a typo?